# Find the interactive elements in a Website using DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, console.log

How to conclude an element is interactable using DOM?

I couldn't find onclick event on some elements in DOM, but they are clickable.

sites build with different framework act differently.

I have tried to loop through all elements under a class or id and if the element have a non-null onclick value a border will be drawn for the element.

Comment: One common way of making elements interact-able is to use `addEventListener`. However this can also be undetectable once it's in place. Even if it were detectable, not all events imply interactivity. For example, `mousemove` can be used for interactivity but is also used for non-interactive tracking.

Comment: Having an event listener does not mean something is interactive, nor the other way round. Especially when event delegation is used.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node-in-javascript-or-in-debugging

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know if an element has an event listener or not

you can set the event listener like this :

```
element.onclick = () => {}
```

rather then this one :

```
element.addEventListener('click', ()=>{})
```

for detecting if some elements have click event set for them or not you can use:

```
elements.forEach((elm) => {
   if(elm.onclick == null) {
       console.log('Null')
   }else{
       console.log(elm.onclick)
   }
})
```

its my first answer in stackoverflow

hope it did help :)

Comment: In my case I am not the one who is writing the code, I am checking it , so If the event is added like element.addEventListener(",()=>{}) is there any option to find it